# What is a good design pattern/structure to represent Direct Acyclic Graph in Java?

Tags: java, directed-acyclic-graphs

I need to store a reasonably large Direct Acyclic Graph in Java (order of 100,000 nodes, depth between 7 and 20, irregular shaped, average depth 13).

What would be the best-performing data structure(s) to store it if the predominant operation I need after building the data structure is:

- 99% operations: Find a full set of accendant paths (from the root down to a given node)
- 1% operations:  Find all children, or more often, all ancestors, of a given node.

As can be obvious, I'd like the first operation to be O(1) if possible, as opposed to O(Average-Depth)

*Please note that for the purposes of this question, the data structure is write-once: after I build it from a list of nodes and vertices, the graph topology will **never change***.

---

My naive implementation would be to store it as a combination of:

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer[]> childrenPerParent;
HashMap<Integer, Integer[]> ascendantPaths;
```

E.g. I store, for each node: a list of children of that node; and separately, a set of paths to the root from that node.

**Downside:** This seems very wasteful as far as space (we basically store each of the inner graph nodes multiples of multiples of times in the ascendantPaths - e.g. given size estimates, we would store extra 100,000 * 13 = 1,3Million node copies in `ascendantPaths`, each of which is an object to be created and stored )

Comment: Is this for a one-off processing job or for a more persistent data set?

Comment: @chrylis - persistent server. It will execute millions of the first type of access (get ascendent paths of a node)

Comment: Then I'd recommend Neo4J.

Comment: Is this an interview question?

Comment: @chrylis - does Neo4J offer me in-memory data storage and O(1) GetAscendantPaths operation? if so, make it an answer.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta - no, it's "I'm writing a new Java server" question. Previous design did these calculations in-Sybase in stored procedures. Why, would the answer change if it was an interview question? :)  Admittedly, I'm a relative Java newbie as my SO account perusal would clearly show :)

Comment: Nah, just curious. I agree with the neo4j suggestion.

Comment: BTW, if the size of your data is not likely to increase drastically you can probably design something like [this](https://oracleofbacon.org/how.php).

Comment: @GiovanniBotta - That's C. I'm assuming Java may impose its own considerations on implementation, e.g. object creation speed

Comment: What do you mean by ascendant path? Shortest path from node v to node u? Or all the paths from v to any other node? What do you mean by finding all children/ancestors? All direct children/ancestors or the subgraph containing a given node?

Comment: @GiovanniBotta - the latter. A full set of paths up (against vertix direction) from the node to the root.

Comment: So the ascendant path is the set of all paths that can reach a given node from the root (that is all the paths in the transpose graph from the node to the root). What about the children/ancestors?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Neo4J](http://neo4j.com/). It's a graph database implemented in Java with a lot of low-level optimizations (e.g., node and edge attributes are stored in their own blocks so that node identities and their edges can be packed), and it mmaps the on-disk database. Following an edge is independent of the number of nodes in the graph or edges on the origin.